# Checking the Diagonalizability of matrix $A^{*}A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

What can say about Diagonalizability of $A^{*}A$ matrix,where $A^{*}$ is tranjugate of matrix $A$

I been searching about the properties of $A^{*}A$ matrix on internet, but find nothing .I have no idea about this matrix, i know little bit about $A^{t}A$ type matrices but still i have no idea about its  Diagonalizability also.

Please Help

Thankyou

Comment: What does tranjugate mean? Is it [conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose)?

Comment: @preferred_anon yes.

Comment: Hint: $A^* A$ is Hermitian.

Comment: @preferred_anon, and Hermitian matrix is always diagonizable in C. why this not come to mind. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You know that $A^*A$ is hermitian because $(A^*A)^*)=A^*A$. By this you know two things that come from Propositions and Theorems studied in any regular Linear-Algebra class.
If a matriz is hermitian then it's eigenvalues are real numbers and it's unitarily similar to a real diagonal matrix. Then $A^*A$ is always diagonalizable.